# Hibernate sub query in from with criteria

Tags: hibernate, subquery, criteria

I have SQL code with sub query.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM DB.A LIMIT 5) AS AA LEFT OUTER JOIN DB.B ON DB.B.b_a = DB.A.a_id;
```

Is it possible to convert it to Hibernate criteria with sub query?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use this kind of subquery in hql even, use sub select in hql